Using textFinder to locate numbers from a column that also includes formulas
I am writing a small script to reconcile bank transactions against recorded budget entries in a sheet. The budget entries also include some formulas, for things such as Supermarket shopping which has many entries for a month. Problem is when I use textFinder, it gets a hit on a partial match when it is in a formula.
function extractFormulas(amount) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("June");
    const lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const receiptsRange = sheet.getRange("C4:C"+lrow);
    var result = null;
    if (amount <= 0) {       //payments are negative in the bank statement
        if (result = receiptsRange.createTextFinder(-amount).matchFormulaText(true).findNext()){
            return(result.offset(0,-1).getValue());     //I'm interested in the adjacent cell contents 
        } else {
        return("not found");
        }
    } else {
        return("deposit");
}

sample data from bank statement after function has executed
Supermarket -160
deposit         2000
Supermarket -45.5
Petrol car & Bike & Rideon  -12

The supermarket match (160) is the 160.76 element
=26.24+39.74+15.37+4.7+41.92+45.5+48.49+133.39+10.19+34.81+26.09+7.7+11.03+19.17+160.76+10.4+298.96+4.2+26.99+335.05
The Petrol car & Bike & Rideon match (12) is the 112.92 element
=36.89+112.92
If I add the matchEntireCell(true) then I dont get hits at all in the formulas
I was expecting a full match not a partial match for each entry in a formula
ie:
=36.89+112.92
a match if and only if either of the 2 entries in the formula was matched (36.89, 112.92)
not a partial match

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function extractFormulas(amount) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("June");
  const lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const receiptsRange = sheet.getRange("C4:C" + lrow);
  if (amount <= 0) {
    const idx = receiptsRange.getFormulas().findIndex(([c]) => [...c.matchAll(/\b[.\d]*/g)].some(([e]) => e == -amount.toString()));
    if (idx > -1) {
      return receiptsRange.offset(idx, -1, 1, 1).getValue();
    } else {
      return ("not found");
    }
  } else {
    return ("deposit");
  }
}


In this modification, from your question, when there is a formula =36.89+112.92 in cells "C4:C", when =extractFormulas(-12) is put into a cell, not found is returned. When =extractFormulas(-112.92) is put into a cell, a cell value of the left side of the cell with =36.89+112.92 is returned.

From createTextFinder(-amount) of your showing script, I used the same value of -amount. Please be careful about this.


References:

matchAll()
findIndex()


Tanaike - thanks for your help. There are still some issues though. But will respond later. Thanks again

@tikitour Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand There are still some issues though.. I understood that you wanted to check only the values 36.89 and 112.92 from =36.89+112.92,  and wanted to confirm that when 12 is used, that is not included in it. If my understanding is not correct, please tell me. At that time, I have to apologize again.

Tanaike
So what I have is column of amounts from a bank statement (which are withdrawals so negative), and I am matching them against a column of manually entered receipts (which are positive).
Some of the manually entered receipts are in formulas, like for instance Supermarket purchases, for which there are many during a month. And some are one off purchases. I want to match against both types of receipts entries.
I'm aware that for numbers the trailing zeroes (cents) are truncated in the bank statement when imported to the sheet.
So the code you submitted looks only at formulas.

@tikitour Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand your current issue of my proposed answer. Can I ask you about the details of it?

function extractFormulas(amount) {
...
if (amount <= 0) {
const idx = receiptsRange.getFormulas().findIndex(([c]) =>
[...c.matchAll(/\b[.\d]*/g)].some(([e]) => e == -amount.toString()));
if (idx > -1) {
return (receiptsRange.offset(idx, 0, 1, 1).getA1Notation()+"|"+receiptsRange.offset(idx, -1, 1, 1).getValue());
} else {
if (result = receiptsRange.createTextFinder(-amount).matchFormulaText(false).findNext()){
return(result.getA1Notation()+"|"+result.offset(0,-1).getValue());
} else {
...

I cant get code editor to save as markup code!! sorry

@tikitour Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from I cant get code editor to save as markup code!! sorry, I cannot still understand your current issue of my proposed answer. Can I ask you about the details of it?

@tikitour I'm not sure about your current issue from your reply. So, this is just my guess. For example, in your situation, v8 runtime has already been enabled? Ref If V8 runtime is disabled, my modified script cannot be used. At that time, please enable it. If my guess was not correct, I apologize.

Use a regular expression with a word boundary \b, like this:
function extractFormulas(amount) {
  const receiptsRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('June!C4:C');
  const search = Math.abs(amount);
  if (String(search) !== String(amount)) return 'not a valid number';
  const finder = receiptsRange
    .createTextFinder(`\\b${amount}\\b`)
    .useRegularExpression(true);
  const result = finder.findNext() || finder.matchFormulaText(true).findNext();
  if (result) return (result.offset(0, -1).getValue());
  return ('not found');
}

See regular expressions quickstart, RegExp and TextFinder.

Thanks @doubleunary
An interesting deployment of \b to separate out the elements of the formula. I have another problem though, and that is not all entries in the manually entered receipts are formulas, most aren't, being one of payments. The solution doesnt capture these?

Edited the answer to search formulas only when a value match is not found.
